# Where should I keep my single instance of my database client in database architecture for microservices?

Tags: c#, architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have this architecture of layers :
Client UI (exe),
Services with ASP .net web api to handle requests from client (.net core app),
Application to do operations, checks ... (.net core class library),
Models is a mapping classes. (.net core class library),
Infrastructure for database handeling. (.net core class library with generic repository).

In the bigenning the Services layer create an instance of my database in the startup and then this instance get passed to bellow layers to application and then from application to the infrastructure layer.
this is done for IoC reasons and to keep a single connection instance of my database client.

Now that I change my database to MongoDb i found myself making some direct dependence between service layer that hold my database client instance and database technology used in infrastructure and then I need to modify my infrastructure and my services as well and this is the problem.

So it's all about architecture, where should I keep my database client instance, in the top level or should only the infrastructure handle this? If so meaning that I need to create new connection each time.

Hope I am enough clear

Comment: What would be the problem injecting a new instance per call of said client into every service of your REST API controllers?

Comment: sounds like: SOLID - Dependency Inversion ...

Comment: Hi nvoigt, the problem of injecting new instance is that the service layer is aware about technology used for database, i mean that service must create MongoClient client = new MongoClient("connectionString")  to passe it to the infrastructure which i don't want, there must be some kind of abstraction to avoid this dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not pass that instance of your database object across your layers. It should stay on a single layer - the data layer. Here is what I mean by that:

- You should have a `data layer` which contains classes modeled through abstractions (interfaces) for the upper layers. For example classes like `User`, `Profile` with methods like `setUserName`, `updateProfile`, etc.
- Each class in the data layer contains a reference to your actual DB client (MySQL, MongoDB, etc). That reference can be a Singleton (which means one connection to your DB).
- Upper layers in the business logic *depend only on the classes of your data layer*, they don't know about your specific DB service. More exactly, *they depend on the interface exposed by the data layer*
- That way, when you want to change your database, you only update the data layer (because there you have the specific database client). The other layers remain unchanged.

Comment: Well i don't understand what you mean really by data layer.
is it a folder inside an existing project (layer) ?
if it so then where ? in application i guess ?
or is it a separated layer (new  project) ?
if it so then it's a class library, and ... we can't store a singleton in non concreate application.
only a concrete application like console, winforme, .net web api (something running) that can keep a singleton.
the only place is the services layers which is running as the others are just class library not ranning to keep some data.

Comment: It is just a folder (with classes) inside your application

Comment: ok but application is a class library, how can it hold a singleton or a data ? it's just been called by the services and pass some parameters to some functions on it, i can't store something on it. maybe i missunderstand something ^^  thanks for responding Cosmin :)

Comment: Well then you may need to do some architectural changes to your application, to avoid the issue of passing that DB instance across the layers. Maybe create a dedicated layer for data management (I see that you have `Infrastructure for database handling` layer). Can't you create one singleton connection there?

Comment: well infrastructure is a class library too, it can't hold a singleton or any data, only services are ranning and can create some concreate objects. i guess i have to create new connection each time request reach low level :s problem with that is i need to read some config file for connectionString, database ... and it's not mean to be used in class library (appsettings.json not included in class library)